# Commerce Product generate Preview on Add Product page

Tags: commerce, entities

I want to add a Preview button in Commerce Product Add form. Before adding product, user can see Preview of Product same as Product Display/Detail page.

I am using Rules to create Product Display after saving Product.

I have added below code in form_alter hook but  :

//Add Preview

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'commerce_product_ui_product_form') {
       $form['actions']['preview'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Preview'),
          '#weight' => 10,
          '#submit' => array('product_preview'),
        );

        // Some special stuff when previewing a node.
        if (isset($form_state['node_preview'])) {
          $form['#prefix'] = $form_state['node_preview'];
          $node->in_preview = TRUE;
        }
        else {
          unset($node->in_preview);
        }
  }
}

function product_preview($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id'] = $productId;
  $node->title = 'test';
  $node->uid = 2;
  $node->type = 'commerceproduct';
  $node->in_preview = TRUE;
  $form_state['node'] = $node;

  node_form_build_preview($form, $form_state);
}
```

Above code displays preview for edit but problem is in node object i am getting $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id'] value not whole Product object. So any updated value of product form fields won't be reflected in preview.

I am not sure how to build whole product object within node object.

Can anyone tell me what is missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering the product entity and attaching it to the form.

To render the product entity (see [entity_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7)):

```
// Extract the referenced product from the node.
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$product = $node_wrapper->field_product->value();

$product_view_mode = 'full'; // Set the view mode you want to use to display this product.

// This will return a render array.
$rendered_product = entity_view('commerce_product', array($product->product_id => $product), $product_view_mode);
```

Finally, alter the form so that it also contains the rendered product.

```
// Now add the markup to the form.
$form['product_preview'] = array(
  '#markup' => render($rendered_product);
);
```

Comment: I have created node-type.tpl.php which is not rendering using above code. It is loading default node.tpl.php.